# Serena Dimensions - 'Work Area Root' deletion

Tags: serena

I have retrieved copies of software baselines from Serena Dimenions into a local folder on my PC for testing but in some cases I don't need to keep a copy on my machine so I delete it.  When I do this I get the error message "This folder is a Work Area root.  Do you want to continue with deletion'.

Can anyone please tell me what a 'Work Area root' is in Dimensions, and whether it is likely to cause any problems if I delete one?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

When working with Dimensions, you check out or get files into a Work Area.  The top directory is where all the project/baseline files and Dimension metadata are contained.

If you delete the local files, then Dimensions gives the warning to insure that you are aware this area is under Dimensions configuration control.

If the folder/work area is under Dimensions, then deletions can potentially involve deletions on the Dimensions server.  As long as you do not Deliver/Commit the deletions, you should be okay.

If you really want to delete files from the server, then that's another matter (probably better handled within Dimensions client) to remove relationships between CM'ed files and specific project/baselines.  They ultimately will still remain in CM (an orphaned file if you will) but would no longer be directly visible as part of that project.

Comment: I believe that if you delete the hidden .dm folder, you cannot commit to dimensions since all the metadata is erased. Also it seems that dimensions keeps track on which work areas you have selected for specific projects, so next time you want to get the project from dimensions it will try to download it to that previous work area and attempt to create the folder if it no longer exists.

Answer (score 0):

Updating your work area from Dimensions will write metadata through the directory structure. It is this that is detected when you try to delete the structure. You can always remove the metadata by right-click on the folder and select 'Disassociate from Source Control' against the Dimensions context menu.   Hmmm... just noticed that this is rather an old question.